# Crash after manually updating GoogleTagManager to 7.1.1

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, google-tag-manager

**NOTE**
: We use cocoapods to get the `GoogleTagManager` frameworks via a separate project, and then manually integrate the static frameworks into our Swift Project.

---

With GoogleTagManager(6.0.0), our app is working fine, same for the GTM features.

Now that we are planning to implement `FirebaseMessaging`, we decided to update GTM first so we can also use the latest version of `FirebaseMessaging`.

Our pod file looks like this:

```
target 'SampleProject'
platform :ios, '10.0'
pod 'GoogleTagManager'
```

Here are the versions after the update:

```
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.3.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.1.7)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.3.0)
Using GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
Using GoogleAppMeasurement (5.3.0)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleTagManager (7.1.1)
Using GoogleUtilities (5.3.4)
Using GoogleUtilitiesLegacy (1.3.2)
Using nanopb (0.3.901)
```

However, some of the dependency frameworks are now just folders with just .h and .m files instead of `.framework`. Adding `use_frameworks!` didn't help.

So we turned to the [framework SDK zip](https://firebase.google.com/download/ios) and grabbed the following `.framework`s version instead(the version matched the ones from the cocoapods):

```
FirebaseCore.framework
GoogleUtilities.framework
nanopb.framework
```

And used the zip's `Firebase.h` and `module.modulemap`.

After setting up `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` to point correctly to `libGoogleAnalytics.a`, and replacing `import FirebaseAnalytics` with `import Firebase`, we were able to build the project.

**ISSUE:**

At launch, the app crashes immediately after this console line(.json filename is masked here):

```
GoogleTagManager info: Attempting to load saved version of container GTM-XXXXXX
```

And below is the stack trace:
[image]

I already checked, `TAGRuntime.js.dat` is added to `Build Phases>Copy Bundle Resources`

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @pcagica we didn't update to 7.1.1 after all. Our initial intention was to update it so we can integrate the latest Firebase Messaging. But because of this issue, we opted to use a lower version of Messaging which is compatible with GTM 6.0.0 instead. An issue was already opened regarding this in the Firebase repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2059

Comment: It was my solution to, I had to use a lower version of GTM to make it work without CocoaPods. Thanks for the answer.